# new pandas data frame fill from continous scrape, column names known

Tags: pandas, beautifulsoup

I scraped data like :

```
for row in stat_table.find_all("tr"):
    for cell in row.find_all('td'):
        print(cell.text)
```

the output looks like this :
1
2019-10-24
31-206
MIL
@
HOU
W (+6)
0
16:35
1
3
.333
0
2

etc.

I created a columns variable:

```
columns = ['G','Date', 'Age','Team',"at","Opp",'Score','Starter','MP','FG','FGA','FG%','3P','3PA',"3P%",
           'FT','FTA','FT%','ORB','DRB','TRB','AST','STL','BLK','TOV','PF','PTS',"GmSC","+/-"]
```

I would like to read in the output and create a new pandas data frame with those columns. Any idea how I can read that in?

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it is split your text so that it becomes a list in your `for` loop and append it to a list of lists(`body`):

```
header = [**your column names**]
body = [] # list of lists

for row in stat_table.find_all("tr"):
    for cell in row.find_all('td'):
        body.append(cell.text.split(' ')) # splitting on space
```

Then, make sure `header` and the lists within `body` are of equal length and:

`df = pd.DataFrame(data=body, columns=header)`

Comment: Unfortunately, this gives me : AssertionError: 29 columns passed, passed data had 2 columns

Comment: `AssertionError: 29 columns passed, passed data had 2 columns` 
This error is telling you that length of data rows are not equal to the columns length.
Because you have 29 column headers, you must split your `cell.text` into 29 delimited parts as well so that the data will fit when you create the `DataFrame`

Comment: How do I do that  ? :(

Comment: You need to find out which parts of `cell.text` you need. For example, when I split your text like

 `"1 2019-10-24 31-206 MIL @ HOU W (+6) 0 16:35 1 3 .333 0 2".split(' ')` it gives 15 items.

For whatever reason you either have:
1) too many columns
2) arn't scraping your data right
3) not splitting your text into the right sections